# Why when i put in the wrong answer, i can't get the output to say Wrong

Tags: java, math

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    String firstname =Keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Welcome "+ firstname+  "!"+ " Please answer the following questions:");
    int x =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;
    int y =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;
    int sum = (x+y);
    System.out.println(x + " + " + y + " = ");
    String answer =Keyboard.nextLine();
    if (sum == (x+y)){
    System.out.println("Correct!");
    }else if(sum != (x+y))
    System.out.println("Wrong!");
```

I have to make a short quiz, but i can't get the output to say wrong. I can get it to say correct, but not wrong.

Comment: What did you try to make it say `Wrong!`?

Comment: if i input the wrong answer, i want it to tell me that i am wrong. Right now it tells me correct every time

Comment: This isn't "Do my homework site". You should've probably read your books or listened in the class. Your mistake just shows us you don't understand the basics of programming.

Answer (score 1):

`sum` is always equal to `x+y` since you assign `int sum = (x+y);`.
You probably want to parse `answer` to `int` and check if it's equal to `answer`.

```
if (sum == Integer.parseInt(answer)) {
    System.out.println("Correct!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Wrong!");
}
```

Comment: we haven't learned what parse is. is there another simple fix